# Expired destination (U.S.) passport; unexpired dwelling (Israel) passport

Tags: usa, passports, paperwork, dual-nationality

Help! I just realized my kids' U.S. passports are expired. Their Israeli passports are not. (They're dual citizens, minors, living in Israel.) They (and I) are scheduled to travel to the States *tomorrow*. What can/should I do? (Note that Israel is a non-ESTA country.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an American Citizen Transit in USA with Expired US Passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59497/can-an-american-citizen-transit-in-usa-with-expired-us-passport)

Comment: Contact the consulate _immediately_ and ask how to get emergency travel documents.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 6):

Unless you can get a same-day passport or transportation letter from the US embassy tomorrow, the simple fact is you're **not** flying tomorrow.

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=US&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=US&selDest=USA&selTrans=Use+ctrl-key+to+select+or+deselect+transit+point%28s%29+above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by Airlines, states:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>     nationals of USA must be **valid on arrival**.

And of course the Israeli passports are not an option as your kids lack visas.

While US citizens cannot be refused to entry to the US, airlines still follow Timatic, so again, you'll have to reschedule your trip (do note that you can get the airport taxes for the unused flight back).

**Note**: To save the costs of a same-day passport/transportation letter, you can fly to Canada and cross by land. For Canada, [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=US&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=CA&selDest=Canada&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C) states:

> Passport Exemptions: Nationals of the USA with a recommended proof of citizenship such as a:
>
> - US birth certificate; or
> - US certificate of citizenship; or
> - US certificate of naturalization.

So that is an option too, and possibly cheaper

Answer (score 1):

You are required to leave Israel on your Israeli passports (as I am sure you know). And if you can get to the US border, as citizens your children must be allowed in. However, there may be an issue with boarding the flight without a visa. Given that the embassy is unlikely to be able to help you on such short notice, I think your best chance is if the children were born in the USA, which would be in the passport. That might be enough to persuade an airline clerk that they are citizens. Similarly, if the children were born in Israel, you could try bringing the [Consular Report of Birth Abroad](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/abroad/events-and-records/birth.html), and seeing if that will persuade the airlines.

Good luck.

Comment: "there may be an issue with boarding the flight without a visa". The simple fact is they're **not** getting onboard on expired passports. US citizens are, by law, supposed to have valid passports, and this reflects the info check-in Clerks will see

Comment: On the other hand, a CRBA is _proof_ of citizenship. Frankly, I'd guess this is up to how the supervisor feels.

Comment: But not one officially accepted for entry by air; thus, not one based on which check-in staff is supposed to board a passenger

Comment: In Israel, sometimes a conflict between the rule and _ta'aseh li tova_ [do me a good deed] is resolved in favor of the latter... which is what this OP will need.

Comment: Haha, I ***highly*** doubt they'll do "a good deed" that they think could cost them between USD 3500 and 4300 ***per person***